# Shape mismatch when using combining layers in Caffe

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, conv-neural-network

I'm using the Caffe library for training a convolutional neural network (CNN). However, I'm getting the following error when using the concat layer to combine the output from two convolutional layers before applying it to a inner_product layer.

```
F1023 15:14:03.867435  2660 net.cpp:788] Check failed: target_blobs[j]->shape() == source_blob->shape() Cannot share param 0 weights from layer 'fc1'; shape mismatch.  Source param shape is 400 800 (320000); target param shape is 400 400 (160000)
```

As far as I know I am using the concat layer in the exact same way as in [BVLC_GoogLeNet](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/models/bvlc_googlenet/train_val.prototxt). The concat layer can be found in my train.prototxt at [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/DbqkTFpd) under the name `combined`. The dimensions of my input blob is `256x8x7x24`, where the data format in Caffe is `batch_size x channels x height x width`. I've tried training both using the pycaffe interface and the console. I get the same error. Below is code for training using the console.

```
solver_path = CAFFE_ROOT+'build/tools/caffe train -solver '
model_path = self.run_dir+'models/solver.prototxt'
log_path = self.run_dir+'models/training.log'

p = subprocess.Popen("GLOG_logtostderr=1 {} {} 2> {}".format(solver_path, model_path, log_path), shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

What is the meaning of this error? And how can it be resolved?

**Update**

As mentioned in the comments the log contains nothing else than the error. The stack trace for the error is the following:

```
@     0x7f231886e267  caffe::Net<>::ShareTrainedLayersWith()
@     0x7f231885c338  caffe::Solver<>::Test()
@     0x7f231885cc3e  caffe::Solver<>::TestAll()
@     0x7f231885cd79  caffe::Solver<>::Step()
@     0x7f231885d6c5  caffe::Solver<>::Solve()
@           0x408d2b  train()
@           0x4066f1  main
```

It should also be noted that my solver and code works fine for training the exact same CNN with only 1 "path" along the network, i.e. without the CONCAT layer.

Comment: are you fine-tuning existing caffemodel params?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you correctly. I'm not gine-tuning any existing model, but creating my own for a new dataset.

Comment: Please describe the data format [256 8 7 24]

Comment: How are you using this model? are you training? using python interface or command line? please post the exact command you are using, and if possible the log output of caffe.

Comment: Since posting log and prototxt can make the question quite long, is it possible for you to post these things in e.g., [pastetbin](http://pastebin.com/) and only post a link in the question?

Comment: Sure, thanks for helping! See the updated post. There's nothing else in the log than the error I've written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue you're having is that your **train** net has been updated to have a concat layer while your **test** net hasn't.

It would explain the 400x400 vs 400x800 issue you're having considering your concat merges two 400x400 layers. I can't know for certain without being able to see your test net.

Comment: Thanks. I've now tried that, but it doesn't make any difference. If you look at your link to the layer definition you will see that the default is axis = 1. So adding this additional concat_param does not change anything :)

Comment: @felbo could you use pastebin to share your solver and the full log output? Also, if you have a separate test net, could you post that?

Comment: Thanks, fixing an error in my test.prototxt made it work! Now I'm curious.. why would a proper test net be needed for training? It never even ran a single iteration of backpropagation.

Comment: @felbo usually every X training iteration you want to see what are the performance of the trained net on the test data - this is why you provide a test net for training.

Comment: @Shai I know. And I am providing test nets that are used for exactly that :) However, I'm still curious as to why the test net would affect training up until training iteration X.

Comment: @felbo this error actually occurs before any training, when you're setting up your solver you want to basically create a duplicate network for your testing. This duplicate network needs to share weights with your training net. The error your seeing is because your training "ip1" needs 400x800 weights, but your test 'ip1" only needs 400x400 so it's confused because the nets aren't 1-to-1.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks!